# Anyway around a fresh clone when using BFG Repo-Cleaner?

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

When using [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) is there any way around not having everyone do a fresh clone? With a large team and multiple branches it is difficult to organize this. I am willing to run bfg multiple times should something be reintroduced as long as I don't have to have everyone re-clone the repo.

I'm thinking remove the files (ie private keys) from history, add them to .gitignore file, git push, and have the team rebase their branch.

Hoping Roberto Tyley sees this and can offer some advice.

Cheers!

Comment: What is BFG? Do you store private keys in a repo?

Comment: The problem with overwriting large swathes of history across an entire repository is that, if someone *doesn't* update to the most recent version, you run the very real risk of the changes you removed making their way back into the repo.  What size of a team are we talking here?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin My mistake. I've added a link for more clarity. We did store private keys in a repo but we have since removed them and want to purge them from the repos history.

Comment: @Makoto its a team of about 50.

Comment: Okay, so that's *quite* a few developers. Is it that you want to avoid the scenario of making everyone reclone, or is it monetarily infeasible to ask them to reclone?

Comment: I'd like to avoid the scenario on making everyone reclone in the case that they have local changes they haven't committed yet. The goal is to make the process as transparent as possible since I am willing to run BFG multiple times.

Comment: Private keys, once compromised, are not private anymore. =)

Comment: If you change history on the repository, all other collaborators will have to pull or re-clone, and they will not be happy with it. That's a bitter truth of editing a shared repo.